# UFW is not filtering traffic routed through bridge

Tags: virtual-machines, bridge, proxmox, ufw

I am experiencing a case where UFW is not blocking packets coming from a VPN host, going through the VPN interface, then through a bridge and finally to a VM. I could configure another firewall on the VM (which I probably will), but I would like to block where the VPN users can access directly from the host. I represented what I want to accomplish in the following ""diagram"":

[image: Diagram]

And this is the actual state of my UFW config:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
<public_ip> 51821/udp      ALLOW       Anywhere
<public_ip> 51820/udp      ALLOW       Anywhere
10.0.0.10 7443             ALLOW       10.0.11.0/24
Anywhere                   DENY        10.0.11.0/24
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.0.10.0/24
<public_ip> 22/tcp         DENY        Anywhere
<public_ip> 8006/tcp      DENY        Anywhere

Anywhere                   DENY FWD    10.0.11.0/24 on wg1
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on vmbr0
```

The expected behavior is that I can connect to 10.0.0.10:7443, from the subnet 10.0.11.0/24, and not to anywhere else by allowing that ip:port and denying all the rest (ufw entries 3 and 4), but still I can connect to 10.0.0.10:22 (ssh) from an IP like 10.0.11.2

Some "denials" are applied already in the app servicing at the ports 8006 and 7443, where they only allow connections from 10.0.10.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/16 respectively.

Comment: UFW (or iptables) doesn't handle bridged traffic by default. You might be accustomed to be working in a Docker environment which loads br_netfilter and changes filtering behavior. In short UFW is not the proper tool for this. You might have to learn how to use something else (eg: directly nftables).